# Else-if statement in Java is not working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, if-statement

So I'm trying to do a simple code with an if-else-if statement, but it isn't working. I have only done if-else before and I am getting confused. Here is the code. Why isn't it accepting my else-if?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DaysOfWeek {
public static void main (String[]args) {
    Double day;
    System.out.print("Enter the day: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    day = sc.nextDouble();
    if (day.equals("Monday"));
    {
        System.out.println("Sounds like someone has a case of the Mondays!");
    }
    else if (day.equals("Wednesday"));
    {
        System.out.println("It's hump day! El ombligo!");
    }
    else if (day.equals("Friday"));
    {
        System.out.println("Finally. It's Friday!");
    }
    else {System.out.println("It's another day of the week.");}
}}
```

Comment: I suspect you want `String` instead of `Double`. `Double` is a floating point number, like 1.25. It will *never* be "Monday" etc. You *also* want to remove the semicolon after each `if` statement, as Tiberiu says...

Comment: Remove the semicolon at the end of the statement. `else if (day.equals("Friday"));` should be `else if (day.equals("Friday"))`

Comment: `if (day.equals("Monday"));` => `if (day.equals("Monday"))` remove the semicolo

Comment: @JonSkeet On *my* calendar Monday is 0.577.

Comment: To explain further: the semicolons after `if` statements effectively "close out" the statement "attached" to the `if`, meaning nothing happens. The `{ [stmts] }` make the subsequent `else` clauses syntactically invalid (I think).

Comment: Use an IDE, not a simple text editor. Seeing error messages as you type, instead of being bombarded by too many when you finally attempt to compile the code, makes it so much easier to write valid code.

Answer (score 1):

1. You want `String day` and `sc.nextLine()` if you want any comparison to work as written
2. if and else if lines should not use `;` - Easier to see if you write like

   ```
    if (condition) {

    }
   ```

Comment: I was so frustrated with the else if lines that I overlooked the double. I will fix that and correct the semicolons

Answer (score 0):

Thank-you everyone for quickly pointing out my semicolons at the end of my if-else-if lines. Also, thank-you for the catch on the string as opposed to double, I knew this part but had overlooked it because I was too frustrated with my confusion of the if-else-if lines. Once I corrected the two issues it worked exactly how I'd intended.

String day and sc.nextLine() replaced Double in order to make a proper comparison.

; was removed from the ends of my if-else-if lines.

I also added a little bit so that it would take various options for days entered

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class DaysOfWeek{
    public static void main (String[]args) {
    String day;
    System.out.print("Enter the day: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    day = sc.nextLine();
    if (day.equals("Monday")||day.equals("M")||day.equals("Mon.")||day.equals("Mon"))

    {
        System.out.println("Sounds like someone has a case of the Mondays!");
    }
    else if (day.equals("Wednesday")||day.equals("W")||day.equals("Wed.")||day.equals("Wed"))
    {
        System.out.println("It's hump day! El ombligo!");
    }
    else if (day.equals("Friday")||day.equals("F")||day.equals("Fri.")||day.equals("Fri"))
    {
        System.out.println("Finally. It's Friday!");
    }
    else {System.out.println("It's another day of the week.");}
}}
```

Comment: I would suggest `matches()` method rather than multiple equals